# Google Sign-in Error 400. Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain

Tags: javascript, php, google-signin, google-oauth

I get the following

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_request
>
> Application: [redacted]
>
> You can email the developer of this application at: [redacted]
>
> Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain.
>
> Request Details That’s all we know.

My code is

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="[redacted]">

<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

Google Dev Console Credientials are:

[Javascript Origins/Authorized Redirected URI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNhy3.png)

**Problem:**

This currently is working fine on the localhost(server : named dev) but when I try to do it from another computer within our network, I get the 400 error. This server is only available within our internal network and is not outward facing.
to Authorized JavaScript origins, Ive also tried adding them to the redirect URI. but continue to get the same error.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I am not expert on this, but here is my opinion.

if you visit that URL in localhost everything is fine.
but if you use IP address 192.168.1.x  that would cause problem.
that are some stackoverflow answer point out this problem.

put that code running at public domain like www.something.com
and use DNS point to your server, that may help.

btw,  you post this question in April. Now is May.
your problem may already solved by yourself?
maybe you can share your solution on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

What @NamNamNam said is true, troublesome attempt when using localhost and thinking it will work the same as the ip address is a mistake. For it to work on other machines, try using ip addresses. It will be better, it worked for me on a lan when I was using facebook api. Still testing it for Google api though, but definitely I saw that it doesn't work if you wish to identify a localhost call using a remote call on a lan by ip address

Comment: Ohh i just realized, google api can't work on a lan cauz it doesn't accept ip address redirects. So, unless you can resolve the ip address to a domain name on your local network the test will only be possible on the localhost machine:) And you will only see it on another machine if it is on a server with a domain name